# Load data from file altering date formats

Tags: php, mysql

I am loading data into MySQL using `LOAD DATA LOCAL IN FILE` as below and I want to change things like date formats as its loaded.

I have tried using `DATE_FORMAT` like below, and also tried adding a PHP function inside the query but that didn't work.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$f."' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE customer_billing_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(
    @cli, 
    @fromdate, 
    @todate, 
    @quantity, 
    @unitcost, 
    @totalcost, 
    @description, 
    @account 
) 
set 
    producttype = DATE_FORMAT(@fromdate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')
```

Comment: You mentioned _altering_ date formats.  So...what's the other format besides `%m/%d/%Y %H:%I` ?

Comment: What is the actual format of the `@fromdate` field in the CSV file?

Comment: @Barmar the format is `DD/MM/YYYY` and i want `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse the date; `DATE_FORMAT()` is for taking a date or datetime and returning a string in the format you want.

```
producttype = STR_TO_DATE(@fromdate, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
```